# Why is first navigator push laggy?

Tags: flutter, navigator

I have an app with a list of tile, when one of them is pressed this page push is triggered :

```
Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) =>
                ExistingAppointment(appointment: _appointment)));
```

When I push for the first time, the animation does not trigger or "freeze". Further navigation animates properly. I made a video here :

[image]

The initial scaffold is as follow :

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: tabs[_selectedIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        selectedItemColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
        showUnselectedLabels: true,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today), label: 'Agenda'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.people), label: 'Patients'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.account_balance_wallet), label: 'Comptabilité'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.settings), label: 'Paramètres'),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the same behavior observed in release mode?

Answer (score 1):

Did you check this open issue on [Flutter Git](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31059)

There are a couple workarounds suggested by some users [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31059#issuecomment-535624611)

Please check if the above mentioned workaround in the following code solves your issue:

> ```
> Future<Widget> buildPageAsync() async {
>     return Future.microtask(() {
>         return HeavyDetailPage();
>     });
> }
> ```
>
> How to use this:
>
> ```
> var page = await buildPageAsync();
> var route = MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => page);
> Navigator.push(context, route);
> ```